# Matplotlib Scatterplot / Color as function of third variable / Symmetric Log Colorscale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot with the points shaded according to a third variable. I want to use a symmetric logarithmic scale for my colormap as described in the api: [SymLogNorm](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm)

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type

Here a mini example. I'm using matplotlib 1.3.0.

```
# loading modules
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# defining variables
x=[0,1,2,3]
y=[0,1,2,3]
c=[-1000,-100,100,1000]

# making scatterplot

plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, norm=mpl.colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=10))
```

Without the symmetric logarithmic colormap the plot works fine.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)
```

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SqSk.png)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? Your "broken" example works for me with 1.3.0.

Comment: I'm using 1.3.0. So I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: Did you try with above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `SymLogNorm` is not particularly clear, as a result I am not confident everything I say in this answer is correct. It seems the  `vmin` and `vmax` arguments should be used to determine the range of data your consider e.g:

```
# loading modules
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# defining variables
x=[0,1,2,3]
y=[0,1,2,3]
c=[-1000,-100,100,1000]

# making scatterplot
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c, s=100, norm=mpl.colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=10, vmin=-1e3, vmax=1e3))
plt.colorbar(ticks=c)
```

[image]

The colorbar ticks are then not going to know that it is log scaled but I think this is the effect you were aiming for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Actually the arguments `vmin` and `vmax` are needed to make SymLogNorm work. It should be written somewhere in the documentation.